# ReferenceError accessing an object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error `ReferenceError: images is not defined` when I set `$scope.primaryImage = images[ii];`

This code lives in one of my controllers:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    Items.get({
        itemId: $routeParams.itemId
    }, function(item) {
        $scope.item = item;

        for(var ii=0; ii < item.images.length; ii++){
            if(item.images[ii].primary)
                $scope.primaryImage = images[ii];
        }
        alert("hey");
    });
};
```

The schema that I'm passing looks like this:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({ images: [ImageSchema]});
```

And ImageSchema looks like:

```
var ImageSchema = new Schema({primay: {type: Boolean, default: false}});
```

I'm very new to angular so let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: `$scope.primaryImage = item.images[ii];` instead of `$scope.primaryImage = images[ii];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like there is no variable 'images' defined, but rather a property of 'item'.